# How return image link

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have image in static files, how i can get link on it from view?

For example, image 'myapp/static/default.png', I want return link on it.

```
def to_representation(self, value):
    url = super(ImageField, self).to_representation(value)
    if not url:
        url = ???
    return url
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this will work fine in your views.py:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.staticfiles import static

url = static('/myapp/default.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

I did:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.storage import StaticFilesStorage

...
storage = StaticFilesStorage()
url = settings.BASE_URL + storage.url('default.png')
...
```